Excel Formula Matching Same data in a Row and next to each other
Good day everyone.
I try to give condition with criteria :
The cell has same value as the cell, at left or right
Data shown below

If the "D" detected contiguous, the Judgement will return "Demotion"
But if the "D" is not contiguous, then nothing happens.
i have no idea how to return it using IF or count.
I already try the IF condition, but still can't figure the "DD" contiguous condition.
Or Countif too, still  can not figure it out.
Picture 2, how to create the start reference id dynamic
Picture 2, 
Thank You

Using Excel 365 (not sure if it's going to work for other versions):
=IF(SUM(IF((B4:E4="D")*(OFFSET(B4:E4,0,-1)="D"),1,0))>0,"Demotion","n/a")



IF((B4:E4="D")*(OFFSET(B4:E4,0,-1)="D"),1,0):

This part of the formula checks if the cells in the range B4:E4 contain the letter "D" and if the cells immediately to their left (using OFFSET(B4:E4,0,-1)) also contain "D".
B4:E4="D" creates an array of TRUE/FALSE values where TRUE indicates the cell contains "D".
OFFSET(B4:E4,0,-1) shifts the range B4:E4 one column to the left, and OFFSET(B4:E4,0,-1)="D" creates another array of TRUE/FALSE values.
Multiplying these two arrays element-wise (*) results in an array where only the positions with "D" in both the current and left cells are TRUE (1), and others are FALSE (0).
IF(...,1,0) converts this array into 1s and 0s.


SUM(...):

The SUM function adds up all the 1s from the previous step, giving the total count of cells in B4:E4 that have "D" and also have "D" in the cell to their left.


IF(SUM(...)>0,"Demotion","n/a"):

Finally, the outer IF function checks if the sum is greater than 0.
If it is, the formula returns "Demotion".
If not, it returns "n/a".




Thanks a lot sir, it works and also could combine with others condition,,
Thank You so much,,
But still i can't understand the logic of your formula sir,, i need a coffee first to break it,,

@G.Will  I've added a detailed explanation of the formula.

Thank You so much sir,, easy too understand,,
Sir, im sorry can i ask you one more thing.
I have an issue, the Cell Start Reference should by start from the Last Promoted Year + 1
i've Try this formula : =IF(SUM(IF((CELL("address",INDEX($N6:$W6,MATCH($F6+1,$N$5:$W$5))):$W6="D")*(OFFSET(CELL("address",INDEX($N6:$W6,MATCH($F6+1,$N$5:$W$5))):$W6,0,-1)="D"),1,0))>0,"Demotion","n/a")
Please kindly find the picture on main post sir,,
i dunno but, can't insert the picture in comment column.

You may try SCAN() function.
=LET(t,SCAN("",B2:E2,LAMBDA(a,x,IF((a=x)*(x="D"),"Demotion",x))),XLOOKUP("Demotion",t,t,"N/A"))

Dynamic spill version-
=BYROW(B2:E5,LAMBDA(r,LET(t,SCAN("",r,LAMBDA(a,x,IF((a=x)*(x="D"),"Demotion",x))),XLOOKUP("Demotion",t,t,"N/A"))))



Thank You so much Sir for the suggestion, really appreciate it, i believe that's the great formula,, but so sorry the formula doesn't work on my excel, maybe it is the different version of excel i use,,
I use ms. office LTSC Professional Use 2021,,  Is it could execute your formula ?

@G.Will No, my formula will work on Microsoft-365.
